# Increment based on condition- SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for a SQL code which can increment a field based on below condition.

I need to create a new field which works with below functionality and with priority

1. If Value_count swipe is null, then new field i.e value_daysworked consecutively should be Null
2. Then if ID_individual is not equal to Previous ID_individual then we need to
   get the new field dependent on value_countswipe if > '0' then '1' else Null
3. If ID_individual = previous ID_individual then check the date field and if date are consecutively then counter remains and once date changes then counter gets reset.

Kindly refer the below input and output which will give you a clear vision.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ7i5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yw1I.png)

NOTE : we don't have to use any variable for it.

Thanks,
Abhishek

Comment: It seems you are under the impression that this is a code or SQL writing service, where you post a very vague description of your problem (without even the effort to provide the details here) and the language of choice, and someone here churns out code for you. You're totally mistaken. We're more than happy to help, but you have to first make an effort to solve the problem yourself. If you run into problems doing so, explain the problem you've encountered, include the relevant information **here**, in the question itself, and ask a **specific question** about the SQL that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

If the meaning of "Previous ID_individual" is the latest record, your table need another column to mark the datetime so that you can use function MAX() to find it.